# Processing reg query output as a single line

Tags: batch-file, registry

I want to get some details from the Windows registry in a single line (one per key) format. But what I have tried so far gives me the details I want, but split over 2/3 lines, which makes post processing harder.

This is on Windows 10.

One option is to query the registry, so I run the following:

`reg query hklm\system\currentcontrolset\enum /s  /f "DeviceDesc"`

This gives me output in the following format (snippet):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\system\currentcontrolset\enum\HID\VID_1A2C&PID_2124&MI_01&Col02\7&2a45f711&0&0001
    DeviceDesc    REG_SZ    @input.inf,%hid_device_system_control%;HID-compliant system controller

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\system\currentcontrolset\enum\HID\VID_1A2C&PID_2124&MI_01&Col02\8&9a82e8&0&0001
    DeviceDesc    REG_SZ    @input.inf,%hid_device_system_control%;HID-compliant system controller

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\system\currentcontrolset\enum\HID\VID_2149&PID_2117&MI_00\7&1e3fba77&0&0000
    DeviceDesc    REG_SZ    @input.inf,%hid_device_touch_screen%;HID-compliant touch screen

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\system\currentcontrolset\enum\HID\VID_2149&PID_2117&MI_01\7&316fd6b5&0&0000
    DeviceDesc    REG_SZ    @input.inf,%hid_device_vendor_defined_range%;HID-compliant vendor-defined device

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\system\currentcontrolset\enum\HID\VID_24AE&PID_2003&MI_00\8&456ad84&0&0000
    DeviceDesc    REG_SZ    @keyboard.inf,%hid.keyboarddevice%;HID Keyboard Device
```

The format is:

```
BLANK LINE
HKEY_LOCAL.....
    DeviceDesc .....
```

What I want is the `HKEY_LOCAL...` and `DeviceDesc` to appear on the same line of output text, so that I can use `FIND/FINDSTR` to get the complete info for the device I am interested in.

With the output as it stands, I cannot get the two piece of information together using DOS commands.

Is there a way to make DeviceDesc appear of the same line ?

I could write a Java/C# for this, but it seems overkill.

Comment: Which device are you interested in?

Comment: @Compo .. it's the 3rd one I want .. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\system\currentcontrolset\enum\HID\VID_2149&PID_2117&MI_00\7&1e3fba77&0&0000`

Comment: That's really an incomplete response and doesn't help us to help you. Are you trying to find the key and/or data with respect to the touch screen, or  anything which falls as the third return from anyone's PC. What specifically are you wanting, the key, the value or the data or some combination of one or more. _For instance, are you trying to parse the data to determine the name of the inf file?_ Your question says you'll be processing the response, so what exactly are you trying to process?

Comment: @Compo, I run a command, it give me 2 pieces of info on separate lines. I can search for the 2nd piece of info, but then my issue which is the corresponding line that contains the 1st piece. In terms of helping, the essence of teh question is about joining 2 line of text into a single line where line 1 starts with `'^HKEY_LOCAL'` and line 2 is the very next line.

Comment: Well, have you got any **special values** that will exist anyway in output **one time** in both two pieces of code? Then, you can use a `for /f` loop. e.g. `for /f "delims=" %%A IN ('reg query hklm\system\currentcontrolset\enum /s  /f "DeviceDesc" ^| findstr /c:7&1e3fba77&0&0000') do set first_line=%%A` and an another one: `for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%B IN ('reg query hklm\system\currentcontrolset\enum /s  /f "DeviceDesc" ^| findstr /c:"touch screen"') do set second_line=%%B`. Then, `set combined=%first_line% %second_line%`. `echo` the result with `echo %combined%`.

Comment: But please make sure that these values will exist **only once**.

Comment: I could provide some code to give you the third registry key in your provided output from your earlier `Reg Query`, but that serves no real world purpose, it serves only to provide you with the third registry key, in that specific output as run by you earlier, _(for all we know, the next time you run that `Reg Query` command, the output will be different)_. Please explain what exactly you are trying to achieve, not just what you think you need.

Answer (score 1):

The command **REG** has no options to define the output format.

A **FOR** loop can be used to concatenate registry key and the device description string value for output on one line. The entire output of **FOR** loop can next be filtered with command **FINDSTR** for the device description of interest:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
(for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\enum /s /f "DeviceDesc"') do if /I not "%%A" == "DeviceDesc" (set "RegKey=%%A") else echo !RegKey!    %%C) | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /C:"HID-compliant touch screen"
endlocal
```

Please note that registry keys or description values containing one or more `!` are not correct processed by this batch code because of enabled delayed environment variable expansion.

There are four spaces used to separate registry key from device description. It is of course also possible to use for example a horizontal tab.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg query /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to combine each lines `Key Path` & `Data`. The easiest way to do this (From My knowledge) Is to grab each result of the `FOR` loop and use an `IF` statement to set the strings we will later combine.

Bellow you will find the script - In my case I just outputted the results to a document. This is fine and can be called later to with a `TYPE` statement inside of a `FOR`. *However* if you want to do something with these variables in the loop, just simply continue your code in-place of the `ECHO [!Location! !Data!] >> Output.txt`.

```
@ECHO OFF
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "RUN=0"
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('reg query hklm\system\currentcontrolset\enum /s /f "DeviceDesc"') DO (

    Rem | Grab & organize output variables to string.
    If "!RUN!"=="1" (

        Rem | Second Cycle
        Set "Data=%%A"
        ECHO !Location! !Data! >> Output.txt

        Rem | Restart Cycle
        Set "Data="
        Set "Location="
        Set "RUN=0"

    ) ELSE (

        Rem | First Cycle
        Set "Location=%%A"

        Set "RUN=1"
    )
)

Goto :EOF
```